# Solve the equation $(D^2+2D+1)y=x\cos x$ where $D=\frac {d}{dx}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the equation $(D^2+2D+1)y=x\cos x$ where $D=\frac {d}{dx}$

My Attempt:
The given equation is
$$(D^2+2D+1)y=x\cos x$$
It's auxiliary equation is
$$m^2+2m+1=0$$
$$(m+1)^2=0$$
$$m=-1,-1$$
$$\textrm {Complementary Function (C.F)}=(c_1+c_2 x)e^{-x}$$
Now, the particular integral is 
$$\textrm {P.I}=\frac {x\cos x}{D^2+2D+1}$$
$$=x\cdot \frac {\cos x}{D^2+2D+1} - \frac {2D+2}{(D^2+2D+1)^2}\cdot \cos x$$
$$=x\cdot \frac {\cos x}{-1+2D+1} - \frac {2(D+1)}{(D+1)^4} \cdot \cos x$$
$$=x\cdot \frac {\cos x}{2D} - 2 \frac {\cos x}{(D+1)^3}$$
How to solve further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking from where you left
$$P.I=x\cdot \frac {\cos x}{2D} - 2 \frac {\cos x}{(D+1)^3}$$
$$=\frac{x\sin x}{2}-2\frac{(D-1)^3}{(D^2-1)^3}\cos x$$
$$=\frac{x\sin x}{2}-\frac{2}{-8}(D^3-3D^2+3D-1)\cos x$$
$$=\frac{x\sin x}{2}+\frac{1}{4}[\sin x+3\cos x-3\sin x -\cos x]$$
$$=\frac{x\sin x}{2}+\frac{1}{2}[\cos x-\sin x]$$

Comment: It should be $-\cos x$ in the $4^{th}$ step. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Here I propose an alternative way to approach it. One has
\begin{align*}
y'' + 2y' + y = x\cos(x) & \Longleftrightarrow (y'+y)' + (y'+y) = x\cos(x)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow z' + z = x\cos(x)\\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (ze^{x})' = x\cos(x)e^{x}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow ze^{x} = \frac{1}{2}e^{x}((x-1)\sin(x) + x\cos(x)) + k\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (ye^{x})' = \frac{1}{2}e^{x}((x-1)\sin(x) + x\cos(x)) + k\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \ldots
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Please elaborate this $(ze^x)'=x\cos x e^x$

Comment: The expression $(ze^{x})'$ equals $e^{x}z' + e^{x}z$. It results from multiplying it by the integratin factor, which in this case is given by $e^{x}$. The same reasoning applies to $(ye^{x})'$: since $z = y' + y$, one has that $ze^{x} = e^{x}y' + e^{x}y = (ye^{x})'$.

Answer (score 1):

$$y_p=\frac {x\cos x}{D^2+2D+1}$$
$$y_p=(x- \dfrac {2D+2}{(D+1)^2})\frac {\cos x}{D^2+2D+1}$$
$$y_p=(x- \dfrac {2}{(D+1)})\frac {\cos x}{D^2+2D+1}$$
$$y_p=(x- \dfrac {2}{(D+1)})\frac {\cos x}{2D}$$
$$y_p=(x- \dfrac {2}{(D+1)})\frac {\sin x}{2}$$
$$y_p=x\frac {\sin x}{2}- \dfrac {1}{(D+1)}{\sin x}$$
$$y_p=x\frac {\sin x}{2}+ \dfrac {D-1}{2}{\sin x}$$
$$y_p=x\frac {\sin x}{2}+\dfrac {\cos x}2-\dfrac {\sin x}2$$
The completre solution is:
$$ \boxed{ y(x)=c_1e^{-x}+c_2xe^{-x}+ (x-1)\frac {\sin x}{2}+\dfrac {\cos x}2 }$$

Answer (score 1):

$\textrm {P.I}=\frac {x\cos x}{D^2+2D+1}$

$= \{x - \frac{1}{D^2+2D+1}•2D+2\}\frac{1}{D^2+2D+1}cosx$

$= \{x - \frac{1}{(D+1)^2}•2(D+1)\}\frac{1}{2D}cosx$

$=\frac{1}{2} \{x - \frac{1}{D+1}•2\}sinx$

$=\frac{1}{2} \{x sinx - \frac{D-1}{D^2-1}•2sinx\}$

$=\frac{1}{2} \{x sinx - \frac{1}{-2}•2(D-1)sinx\}$

$=\frac{1}{2} \{x sinx + cosx - sinx\}$

Answer (score 1):

You were almost done
$$y_p=x\cdot \frac {\cos x}{2D} - 2 \frac {\cos x}{(D+1)^3}$$
Expand $(D+1)^3=D^3+3D^2+3D+1$
$$y_p=x\frac {\sin x}{2} - 2 \frac {\cos x}{-D-3+3D+1}$$
$$y_p=x \frac {\sin x}{2} -  \frac {\cos x}{(D-1)}$$
$$y_p=x \frac {\sin x}{2} +  \frac {(D+1)\cos x}{2}$$
$$y_p=x \frac {\sin x}{2} + \frac {\cos x}{2}-\frac {\sin x}{2}$$